# Comparing 2 Dropdown component from W3C, one Dropdown is read by NVDA on Firefox correctly, but other doesn't

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility

I was comparing two Dropdown component from w3c.
With this dropdown https://w3c.github.io/aria-practices/examples/combobox/combobox-select-only.html when tested with NVDA on Firefox, when an item is selected from dropdown, item is not getting read by NVDA at all. However, this example https://w3c.github.io/aria-practices/examples/combobox/combobox-autocomplete-list.html is read properly both on Chrome and Firefox. I compared html structure for both specifically `role` attributes and they are structured the same. Only difference is first example use all `div` tags while latter one uses `ul` and `li`. So in the inspector, I even changed `div` to `ul` and `li`, but screen reader still didn't read out the item. What could be the reason first example is not being read properly by NVDA on Firefox?

Answer (score 1):

The two examples are actually quite different.  The first one that "doesn't work" is a `<div>`

```
<div aria-controls="listbox1" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-labelledby="combo1-label" id="combo1" class="combo-input" role="combobox" tabindex="0" aria-activedescendant="" aria-live="polite">Durian</div>
```

The second one that does work is an `<input>`.

```
<input id="cb1-input" class="cb_edit" type="text" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="cb1-listbox" aria-activedescendant="">
```

In the second one, when a selection is made, the `<input>` is given the value of the selection and NVDA reads that value by default because it automatically reads when an `<input>` changes.

In the first one, when a selection is made, the text is just inserted inside the `<div>` and there isn't any default behavior for NVDA to read the new text.  However, you can fix this by adding [`aria-live`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-live) to the `<div>`.

```
<div aria-live="polite" aria-controls="listbox1" ...>Durian</div>
```

Comment: Should this be reported as a bug on the APG?

Comment: As coded, both examples pass WCAG.  The name, role, and value of the combo are properly announced. From a UX perspective, it'd be nice to have the value announced when it's selected but that's not strictly required. Granted, the APG should give examples of best practices, including good UX practices, but one could potentially argue that hearing the value again after it's selected is "noise".

Comment: As per team Mozilla this is bug from Firefox and was fixed for version 109 which will be released tomorrow https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1631693 I'll test this component again tomorrow in Firefox v109.